# Blender 2.8 Objects move when Export to Unity

Tags: animation, objects, bones, unity

I'm hoping I don't have to start over, but I am pretty new to blender and I am not sure if I set up the rig correctly. I have been unable to find a solution, or the proper set up for objects that move based on an IK arm in Unity. I tried baking the animations but that did not work either. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks.

[image: How it looks in Blender]

[image: How It looks in Unity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the local transforms are not 0
apply the local transforms.
you can do that in unity of blender.
in blender just use alt + r for zeroing rotation (or alt +g for move and alt+s for scale)
if you need to apply them use ctrl + a and select accordingly.

you might need to adjust your transform after doing so, so I recommend using some placeholders first.

Comment: Thanks, This worked in Unity. How can I set up the rig to avoid this in Blender, because I was not able to get it to work from Blender to Unity. Do I animate first, than Zero out? Do I zero out before animating?

Comment: make sure everything is zeroed in blender.
also there are options in export and import. make sure the both are correctly set and in unity set them up correctly

Comment: I zeroed everything and it still moves when importing to unity. Best place to find the options online? Videos I see just bring in the blender file and it works, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Edit: I found that everything has to be done in the rest position first before animating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export in your T pose or your rest pose, should be found in blender on your first IK animation frame.